# Pushing to a Github Gist gives invalid request (receive-pack)

Tags: git, github, gist

Can anyone tell me how why I can not push to my gist, I cloned it, so as you can see I have a valid origin.

```
[~/Code/_experimental/hide]$ git remote -v

origin git://gist.github.com/1893380.git (fetch)
origin git://gist.github.com/1893380.git (push)

[~/Code/_experimental/hide]$ git pull origin master

From git://gist.github.com/1893380
 * branch master -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.

[~/Code/_experimental/hide]$ git push origin master

fatal: remote error:
  Your Git client has made an invalid request:
  0037git receive-pack /1893380.git
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the git protocol for cloning. Usually, pushing over the git protocol is disabled. You should use the ssh url (shown as "Private Clone URL").

Comment: Your right, I just realised the same after trying again and came here to self answer. You beat me to it :)